# How to generate a WAR file for a Java project without Maven or Eclipse

Tags: java, tomcat, war

I am working on a Java Web App project. This project has a fixed file structure and does not use Maven. I want to generate a WAR file so that I can deploy it to Tomcat.

I want to generate the WAR without Eclipse, just via the Java tool chain. Is this possible?

I have put together a minimal reproducible example with the same file structure in a git repo at https://github.com/halloleo/ContextListenerJavaWebAppSampleProject.

Comment: See this, may help: [https://www.javatpoint.com/war-file](https://www.javatpoint.com/war-file)

Comment: And see also this, i think your file structure does not meets recommendations. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(file_format)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(file_format)) and [https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19199-01/816-6774-10/a_war.html](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19199-01/816-6774-10/a_war.html)

Comment: @szeak when in "working against the tools" mood, there is no recommended file structure :-)

Comment: Not sure why you are avoiding build tools but a war file is really just a jar file with a particular structure, so if the contents are right, invoke the `jar` command on it.

Comment: A WAR file is a ZIP file with filename suffix .war and a specific internal structure as shown by the link szeak has given to you. So compile your project, create an empty folder, copy all needed artefacts to that folder to their specific place according to the expected file structure and then use a packer tool or the jar tool to create the WAR file out of this. Should be fairly easy.

Comment: @szeak Thanks for chiming in! Your links and details are great.

Comment: @vanje Thanks for chiming in too! Your explanation makes total sense.

Comment: @g00se The reason why I want to avoid a build tool is that others in the team just use it as an Eclipse project, but I am moving to VS Code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A WAR file is a archive (zip/jar) that follows a certain structure. See [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-java-4th/9781449372477/ch15s03.html) for more details.
If you want to create a WAR manually you will need to create the structure manually and then create an archive with the extension of `.war`.

Here is a quick and dirty ant script that can create a WAR file from your structure posted on GitHub

```
<!-- Compile the classes and copy other files to conform to the WAR structure -->
<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="build/WEB-INF/classes" />
    <copy file="WebContent/index.jsp" todir="build" />
    <copydir src="WebContent/WEB-INF/" dest="build/WEB-INF/" />
    <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/WEB-INF/classes" classpath="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar" />
</target>

<!-- Create the WAR file -->    
<target name="war">
    <mkdir dir="dist" />
    <war destfile="dist/test.war" basedir="build" webxml="WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml"/>
</target>
```

Save this as `build.xml` and run `ant clean compile dist` to generate the WAR file in `dist` directory.

**NOTE**: You may have to install the ant tool if you already dont have it. Also, if you want to go complete tool free - you can read the `build.xml` file and convert the steps into a 'batch' / 'shell' script (all the steps are self explanatory).

**CONCLUSION**: Hope this helps. But I still recommend using a tool like Maven or Gradle these will come in handy when the project grows (specially when there are several libraries along with their dependencies)

Comment: Excellent. I will try this out. I might think about a built tool just for the war bundling. The dependency management has to be done manually, because other people in the team rely on the referenced libraries just being checked-in in the lib directory (they use the project just in Eclipse without Maven).